# Nunjucks throws error in template loop

Tags: javascript, nunjucks

I have the following code:

```
var items = [{'name': 'item1'}, {'name': 'item2'}]
var items = nunjucks.render('items.html', items);
```

And template:

```
{% for item in items %}
    {{ item.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: s.fromIterator is not a function
at Object.e.prettifyError (nunjucks-slim.min.js:2)
at nunjucks-slim.min.js:2
```

When I try render a single item, ie not in an array and no loop in the template, it renders fine and there is no issue.  The error isn't really much to go on and nothing turns up in a google - any idea what might be wrong or how to troubleshoot further?

Answer (score 0):

Try change `var items = nunju...` to `nunju...`.

```
// example 
var nunjucks  = require('nunjucks');
var env = nunjucks.configure();
var items = [{'name': 'item1'}, {'name': 'item2'}];

var res = nunjucks.renderString(`
    {% for item in items %}
    {{item.name}}
    {% endfor %}`, 
    {items}
);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, i found in the end this was a version mismatch, i pinned gulp-numjucks and numjucks-slim to the same version 3.0.1 to resolve.